# Any shorter and computationally faster expression of checking if x in Array || y in Array || z in Object keys in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to check if `x`, `y` or `z`(all string and not numerical) exists in the Object keys, my longer expression:

```js
if (x in demoObject || y in demoObject || z in demoObject){
 // do the following action
}
```

Is there a shorter and computationally faster way to do it(if can't achieve both of them at the same code, I want the solution for each side), if I need to check more than 10 values whether they exist in the object keys?

Comment: Not that's awesome, but you can check for a set of keys against the entire set of keys, but it won't be any faster (likely incrementally slower, but that's just a guess).

Comment: `if ([x, y, z].some(key => key in demoObject))`

Comment: barmar solution is not entirely accurate with use of 'in'

Comment: @twalow Why not? Looks good to me.

Comment: @twalow The origincal code uses `in`. My code is equivalent. Of course, it might be better to use `demoObject.hasOwnProperty()`, but that applies to both versions.

Comment: Sadly it's not the same and it's an overlooked issue with using `in`. Try adding "hasOwnProperty" in your example after the z in your array and it will result in returning true.

Comment: @Barmar
example:
const demoObject = {
  3: 'hello',
  5: 'world'
};

const look_for_these = [ 1, 4, 2, 'hasOwnProperty];

const has_key = look_for_these.some(key => (key in demoObject));

console.log(has_key);
// true (when it should be false

Comment: @twalow example `{ hasOwnProperty() { return true; } }` - run your solution through it

Comment: Numbers of values are getting more and more means what? More x, y, z values or the object is getting bigger?

Comment: Who is going to add "hasOwnProperty" to the edge case list of the array of checked values. lol Some people over engineer.... :)

Comment: @twalow Whether or not equivalency is needed or wanted is contextual; the code provided was equivalent--it's up to the OP to decide whether or not the original code is **correct** given their context. The comment you're replying to already stated there's a difference between `in` and `hasOwnProperty`.

Comment: If you're checking "lots" of keys I would move to an array or set approach. But now we're entering over-thinking territory--if performance is an issue benchmark after you have resolutions and have determined the speed differences actually matter.

Comment: There's more info needed. Do the number of keys change on the demoObject? Are they all numerical?

Comment: The demoObject is from the function input, so it changes, not static, they are all strings. @twalow

Comment: '4' is a string, but are your keys all numerical?

Comment: they are not numerical. @twalow

Answer (score 0):

You could take the prototype function [`Object.hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) and handover the object as `thisArg`.

```js
const
    demoObject = { 3: 'hello', 5: 'world' },
    look_for_these = [ 1, 4, 5 ],
    has_key = look_for_these.some(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty, demoObject);

console.log(has_key);
```

Comment: Aside: note the note: "Note: Object.hasOwn() is recommended over hasOwnProperty(), in browsers where it is supported."

Answer (score 0):

```
[x, y, z].some(key => typeof demoObject[key] !== 'undefined')
```

or in your example

```
[x, y, z].some(key => key in demoObject)
```

`Array.prototype` iterate extremely fast (V8 engine → C), though I'm not sure what the fastest 'does this key exist' function would be, if you're testing performance I'd make sure the function and variable definitions happen before the actual performance check, and I'd try larger datasets

Answer (score 0):

As you are asking regarding performance and shorten code, lets see:

**Performance**

Regarding the performance or computation, it is already fast.

The reason is that, you are using **OR operator**. So if first expression gets true, then it will not check the other conditions and get inside the if block. In the worst case scenario, it needs to check all.

**In VS Object.hasOwn()**

Note that by using In, you are checking if the key is present in the object, and if it's not present then it will check in its prototype chain.

While, the Object.hasOwn() checks for the key only on the object.

Also, Object.hasOwn() is a replacement of Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty(). So you can safely use Object.hasOwn().

If you just need to check on the object, use Object.hasOwn().

**Shorter Syntax**

Yes the syntax can be short while maintaining the same performance. Combine the keys that need to check in a array and then use some() function on a array which will return true if any of the provided key is present in the object.

Here is the example snippet:-

```
const obj = {
    1: "a",
    2: "b",
    3: "c"
};

const find = [1,4,6];

if(find.some(f => Object.hasOwn(obj, f))){
  // true
}
```

***Note that:*** I am assuming that we are only interested in the object itself and not on its prototype chain.

Answer (score -1):

Your example effectly has:
O(n) || O(n) || O(n) [ I'm assuming this is the implementation of Javascript for...in. Though it is likely O(1) when used with Objects ].

This example has O(n) search & O(log n) to insert into set:

```js
const demoObject = {
   "pizza": "slice",
   "orange": "peel",
   "carrot": "stick"
};

const x = "grapes";
const y = "melon";
const z = "carrot";

const needles = [x,y,z];
const haystack = new Set(Object.keys(demoObject));

if (needles.some((needle) => haystack.has(needle)))
{
    console.log("Needle found!");
}
```

Comment: `in` is not O(n). Objects are hash tables, so key lookup is O(1).

Comment: But for some reason they are significantly slower to lookup. Otherwise the tests made here would be much closer: https://github.com/anvaka/set-vs-object

Comment: Actually, there's a little difference -- it also searches the prototype chain. But plain objects only have one prototype in the chain.

Comment: That's probably the reason for the 2x speed. It's looking in just one hash table instead of two.

Comment: Also a real hashtable can have both numerical and string keys. Whereas javascript objects cannot do this.

Comment: It allows numeric keys, it just stringifies them first. So that will cause a little extra overhead if you try to look up a numeric key.

Comment: @Barmar It just overwrites. You can't have a string key '1' and a numeric key 1 in same object.
const x = {
    1: 4,
    '1': 8};
console.log(x) only shows one. Whereas Map() can have both.

Comment: Like I said, it stringifies it first. So `1` becomes `'1'`

Comment: Right,. so that's not a true hashmap. Hashmaps create unique keys based on type and value.

Comment: But this is really irrelevant for the problem at hand. Since they want to check existence in an object, they already can't be duplicated. So it's not necessary to convert to a type that distinguishes them.